# XPath count() function

Tags: xml, xpath

Suppose I have an XML tree as below:

```
proceedings
   -name
   -contents
      -article
         -author
         -title
         -pages
```

How can I identify any title that has only one author? And the number of articles that have more than three author using XPath?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Title with one author:

```
/proceedings/contents/article[count(author)=1]/title
```

Number of articles with more than three authors:

```
count(/proceedings/contents/article[count(author)>3])
```

Comment: Either way I can use // to indicate the parent of a child. In this case, `//article[count(author)=1]/title`. Thanks a lot Francis!