# XPath: Get tables with exactly two columns

Tags: php, xpath

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>A</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>B</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>1</th>
    <td>A</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>2</th>
    <td>B</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>A</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>B</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How do I get only the table(s) with `exactly 2 columns`, whether its both `th` in a single `tr`, or both `td` or either, but two columns.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XPath count() function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10176657/xpath-count-function)

Comment: @miken32 ah great! `/table/tr[count(td)=2]` ?

Comment: I think that would return the `tr` elements. Maybe `//table[count(td)==2]` though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check if count of either `th` or `td` in each row equals 2, this is one possible way :

```
//table[tr[count(td|th) = 2]]
```

And if child of `tr` is always either `th` or `td`, never other element that you don't want to consider in the count, then you can just say *count all child elements* :

```
//table[tr[count(*) = 2]]
```

Notice that the above will count only *direct child*, not including descendants.

Comment: I modified it to include optional elements like tbody, thead etc but it now selects the `tr` instead of the table `//table[/*[self::tbody or self::thead or self::tfoot]/tr[count(*) = 2]]`

Comment: Updated my initial XPath which return the `tr` to make it return the table instead...

Comment: As for your attempted XPath, remove `/` in `/*[self::...`, or add a `.` before the `/`. Relative XPath never starts with `/` (you want the expression to be relative to current `table`, so don't start with `/`).

Comment: I tried both (remove `/` and adding `.`) but still get `Warning: DOMXPath::query(): Invalid expression in`

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem. The expression is valid XPath : http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/c84d05c29fbabf6675a4f9047d401db7 . Even no error using DOMXPath: https://eval.in/694387

Comment: Yes, it even works in Chrome just not with my PHP code. Maybe the XPath version is different? Edited to add: Ah! Thats it. PHP is on 1.0