# Manipulating DOM in PHP

Tags: php, symfony, dom, xpath

Although I've been using [DomCralwer](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html) throughout my project, but it has a bug with this XPath query `//table[*[self::tbody or self::thead or self::tfoot]/tr[count(*) = 2]]` therefore, as a workaround, I'm trying to use the built-in functions:

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($tables); $i++) {

  $tables[$i] = purifyTables($tables[$i]);
  echo($tables[$i]);

  $dom = new DOMDocument();
  $dom->loadHTML( $tables[$i] );
  $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
  $nodes =  $xpath->query("//table[*[self::tbody or self::thead or self::tfoot]/tr[count(*) = 2]]");
  echo($nodes);
  echo($dom->saveHTML($nodes));

}
```

... but the output is unexpected:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      WII 5-IN-1 SPORTS KIT H7/10 5-in-1 Glow-in-the-Dark Sports
      Pack for Wii
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Our Price: $19.99 Sale: $5.00 You Save: 75%
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
DOMNodeList Object
(
    [length] => 0
)

PHP Warning:  DOMDocument::saveHTML() expects parameter 1 to be DOMNode, object given in /var/www/html/myscript.php on line 195

Warning: DOMDocument::saveHTML() expects parameter 1 to be DOMNode, object given in /var/www/html/myscript.php on line 195
```

Comment: Your XPath selects all `table`s having a (`tbody`, or `thead`, or `tfoot`) child with a `tr` element having eactly two child nodes. Since the sample HTML doesn't match the conditions, you get an empty `DOMNodeList`. It's not quite clear what you are asking, or what trying to do.

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov `tbody`, `thead` and `tfoot` are optional, no?

Comment: at least one of them must be there to match the expression

Comment: Aah, ok. What I'm trying to do is find all tables with exactly 2 cols (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41070930/xpath-get-tables-with-exactly-two-columns/41072128#41072128) but since some tables have tbody etc I added a condition of that.

Comment: `//table[(.|tbody|thead|tfoot)/tr[count(*) = 2]]`?

Comment: Darn, that worked! I spent half a day fixing this. Thanks heaps!

Comment: I think you should update the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XPath expresson

```
//table[*[self::tbody or self::thead or self::tfoot]/tr[count(*) = 2]]
```

selects all `table`s having a `tbody`, `thead`, or `tfoot` child (only one of them) with a `tr` child having exactly two child nodes. Since the table in the sample HTML doesn't match the expression, you get an empty `DOMNodeList`. It doesn't match, because the `table` element has none of the listed children (`tbody`, `thead`, or `tfoot`).

In the comments to the question I have figured out that you are trying to fetch all tables with exactly two columns. You can do this with the following XPath expression:

```
//table[(.|tbody|thead|tfoot)/tr[count(td) = 2]]
```

The tags `tbody`, `thead`, and `tfoot` are optional due to inclusion of the reference to the table tag (`.`) into the sequence of OR'd elements. The `count` function selects only `td` elements.