# Using XPath count function

Tags: java, xml, oracle, xpath, count

I am using a oracle sql database to carryout sql queries with xpath expressions – I have created an XML file which contains data relating to a film

Comment: What's SQL got to do with XPath?

Comment: What on earth is going on here...

Comment: @shmosel - SQL with support for an XML datatype and XPATH within an XML column

Comment: This is ment to be a programming challenge and I was told to use an oracle sql database and carryout sql queries with xpath expressions

Comment: Maybe you should have mentioned that in the question. Either way, what you have doesn't look anything like what I'm seeing [in the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14288/exprn_xpathpredicates.htm).

Answer (score 0):

The XPath expression you're looking for (not the SQL expression) is:

```
count(/film/directors/director)
```

which result should be `1` with your example XML file.
If you want to check if it's `2`, use

```
count(/film/directors/director) = 2
```

which should return `FALSE` with your XML file.

Answer (score 0):

First, you obviously know you need to use xPath to query the XML file, but you seem to have failed to understand what xPath is or how it should be used.

My first suggestion would be to go a read up on [xPath](https://www.google.com.au/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=xpath&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=p2a9WuHcJbDM8gf5yr_AAg) and [xPath in Java](https://www.google.com.au/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=java+xpath&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=iGa9WumvArDM8gf5yr_AAg) because it has nothing to do with the SQL.

I then did a quick search on "java xpath count" and come across a number of excellent examples, but based on [XPath count() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10176657/xpath-count-function), I went about testing your document with...

```
try {
    DocumentBuilderFactory f = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder b = f.newDocumentBuilder();
    // This is your document in a file
    Document d = b.parse(new File("Test.xml"));
    d.getDocumentElement().normalize();

    String expression = "//film[count(directors)=1]";
    XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    Object result = xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(d, XPathConstants.NODESET);

    NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;
    System.out.println(nodes.getLength());
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {

        Node node = nodes.item(i);
        System.out.println("Found " + node.getTextContent());
    }
} catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | IOException | XPathExpressionException | DOMException exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
}
```

This basically listed the `film` node (found one match) ... but, why did you produce a result?! Look at the query, `//film[count(directors)=1]`, it's listing all `film` matches with a one director, because I want to test the query.  Change it to `//film[count(directors)=2]` and it will return a result of zero matches based on your example.

I would highly recommend that you pause for a moment and become more familiar with what xPath is and how it works before you continue