# How to get the count of elements within a table with two class names?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver

I need to get the len of tds and trs from a table, I am using xpath but whenever I run the code I get values completly different from the correct ones;

The table follows this scheme:

```
<table class="kktable stats">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td></td>
...
</tr>
```

My current attempt:

```
tr_ = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//table/tbody/tr')
tds_ = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//table//tbody//tr[1]//td')

print(len(tr_), len(tds_))
```

¡This should output 34, 13 but it outputs 43, 35 and I need something non absolute because the page changes daily!

> the class of the table is kktable stats

I am currently using this method down bellow /

```
table = '/html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div[6]/div[3]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/table/tbody'
trs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(table+"/tr")
tds = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(table+"/tr[1]/td")
```

This is outputting correctly => 34, 13

I've also tried this:

```
tds_ = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//table[@class="kktable.stats"]//tbody//tr[1]//td')
```

But unfortunately it returned 0

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML

Comment: Look at xpath `count`. E.g https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10176657/xpath-count-function or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13799263/use-of-count-in-xpath-expressions?rq=1

Comment: why are you using "kktable.stats" ?
why dot instead of space?

Comment: it does not work without a "." that is how nested classes work with ¡selenium!

Comment: @AndrejHatzi You are confusing CSS selectors using `.` to specify classes and XPaths. Your last XPath should be `...[@class="kktable stats"]...` as Harshit suggested.

Comment: I've already tried that, it returned ¡nothing!

Answer (score 0):

To get the count of `<tr>`s you can use:

- *CssSelector*:

  ```
  trs = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("table.kktable.stats > tbody tr")
  print(len(trs))
  ```
- *XPath*:

  ```
  trs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@class='kktable stats']/tbody//tr")
  print(len(trs))
  ```

To get the count of `<td>`s from the first `<tr>` you can use:

- *CssSelector*:

  ```
  trs = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("table.kktable.stats > tbody > tr td")
  print(len(tds))
  ```
- *XPath*:

  ```
  tds = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@class='kktable stats']/tbody/tr//td")
  print(len(tds))
  ```